# Silverlight windows authentication

Tags: silverlight, active-directory

I am using Silverlight 4 business application and windows authentication, works fine i get the user logged in, my question is how to get information such as the first name and last name of the logged in user. Right now in the Display friendly name it just show the domain/username.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem a few years back in a Sharepoint app.  I wrote up a [few solutions](http://faxt.com/blog/post/2009/11/25/Identify-the-Active-Directory-Username-from-Silverlight-app-from-Sharepoint.aspx), maybe one will be helpful to you?

Short summary:  1. Page.User.Identity.Name.Split('\')[1](http://faxt.com/blog/post/2009/11/25/Identify-the-Active-Directory-Username-from-Silverlight-app-from-Sharepoint.aspx); or 2. HttpContext.Current.Profile.UserName or some javascript:

```
<script type="text/vbscript" language="VBscript">
    Dim X
    set X = createobject("WSCRIPT.Network")
    dim U
    U=x.UserName
    'MsgBox "username: " & U
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    var a = U;
    $("#name").text(a.toString());
</script>
```